# How to define a dependency to take the Snapshot?

Tags: java, maven, hsqldb

How can I tell `Mave`n to take a specific snapshot from only one of my dependencies?

I'd like to have `HSQLDB 2.3.0` SNAPSHOT from http://www.hsqldb.org/repos/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/SNAPSHOT/, how can I get this into maven?

Comment: Just use the SNAPSHOT as part of the version where you defined the dependency.

Comment: Well the snapshot is not a defined dependency. It just can be downloaded from the link I provided as `http://www.hsqldb.org/repos/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/SNAPSHOT/hsqldb-20130613.093619-50.jar`. How can this be resolved by maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the HSQLDB Guide:

http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/deployment-chapt.html#dec_snapshot_repos

The idea is to use the latest snapshot automatically.